# how do i get the last watched video in my youtube history with python?

Tags: python, youtube

I want to make a python script that gets the link of the last video i watched on my account

From what i found people say that the YouTube API3 discontinued the use of a watch history playlist, so i've been trying to get beutifulsoup to scrape the watch history it only scrapes the youtube.com but not youtube.com/feed/history when i run my script.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as s:

    p = s.post("https://www.youtube.com/feed/history", data={
        "email": 'username',
        "password": "pass"
    })
    print(p.text)

    base_page = s.get('https://www.youtube.com/feed/history')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(base_page.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go check out https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python
This tells you everything you need to know about acessing youtube through python

Comment: as i said the YoutubeAPI discontinued the use of watch history it returns nothing if you try to get the watch history even if you give it an API_KEY and everything

Comment: i might be wrong but thats what the answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463723/youtube-api-v3-returns-truncated-watch-history) was